# buttons with no href, onclick etc

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick, href

Lately, I've been seeing a lot of sites that have clickable objects that don't have any hrefs or onclicks in their html code. I also tried alerting their href, onclick, onmousedown, onmouseup attributes but it only says "undefined". I do notice that there's a lot of complicated javascript in these pages.

one site in particular baffles me:
http://www.sharenator.com/Boy_Teaches_His_Puppy_How_to_Eat/#/doggy_01_Boy_Teaches_His_Puppy_How_to_Eat-0.html

It's actually pretty good. The buttons aren't selectable as well. The ids of the buttons are nextBtn, nextBtn2, prevBtn and prevBtn2.

Anybody has any idea how to implement this?

Comment: @karunchadhary I can see you just registered, so welcome to the StackOverflow community :) If one of the answers answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's .click(callback) function (http://api.jquery.com/click/) or .delegate(selector, 'click', callback) (prior to jQuery 1.7) and .on('click', selector, callback) (jQuery 1.7+) or .bind('click', callback).

Thanks to Anthony Grist for pointing out that .live() is now deprecated :)

As so:

```
<button id="clickable">Click Me!!</button>
```

Then target the button with jQuery:

```
$("#clickable").click(function(){
    // Send user to this link
    location.href = "http://www.takemehere.com";
});
```

You can read more about this on the link I gave, and on jQuery's homepage.

**UPDATE**

The actual page handles this with:

```
$('#prevBtn').mousedown (onBackward);
```

Which would onmousedown call:

```
function onBackward () {
    showImg (currentId - 1);
}
```

The use of arrow keys:

```
 $(document).keyup (function (event) {
    var activeElement = document.activeElement.tagName;
    if (activeElement == 'INPUT' || activeElement == 'TEXTAREA') return;
    //alert (window.location.pathname);

    if (event.keyCode == 39) onForward();
    else
    if (event.keyCode == 37) onBackward();
});
```

See http://www.sharenator.com/js/slideshow.js for the source code of the slideshow.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` (prior to jQuery 1.7) instead.

Comment: how does it implement navigation between pictures with "left" - "right" arrows?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thanks for pointing that out, hadn't read the documentation in awhile :) Edite my code to your suggestion.

Comment: It might be this as it's in most of the websites. Iv'e been putting off learning jquery. But I guess I have to start

Comment: @karunchaudhary jQuery is a wonderful and powerful tool, I would definitely recommend learning how to use it :)

Comment: @Chrules thanks, it will be quite helpful for me in the near future

Answer (score 0):

With javascript, find the element and give it an onClick event handler. e.g.:

```
var myElement = document.body;  // or document.getElementById(...), etc.
myElement.onclick = function(event) {alert(event);}
```

This will avoid showing anything in the HTML, and is how the website you linked does it (there is no other way to define behavior... except maybe esoteric CSS).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the jQuery ui library - this can create buttons in the way you specify.

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The event handlers are probably bound using a Javascript framework such as jQuery. They don't use the `onclick` property of the DOM element. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tJpTf/) for an example of binding a `click` event handler to a button with jQuery, then click the button to see the value of `onclick` for that button (displays as `null` in FF 9).

Answer (score 0):

With javascript. Here's an example:

```
<a id="uniqueId" href="#">Button</a>

<script>
    var button = document.getElementById('uniqueId');
    button.onclick = function(e) {
        alert("clicked!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that I would still see the function when I run: `alert(document.getElementById('uniqueId').onclick)`

Answer (score 0):

the click functions may be initialized in js, for example, $("#nextBtn").click(function);