# Button onClick event and Href-Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, location-href

I used a solution given by "Chrules" found in this discussion:[buttons with no href, onclick etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816916/buttons-with-no-href-onclick-etc/10257455#10257455)

like this :

```
<button id="clickable" >Click Me!!</button>
 ......
$("#clickable").click(function(){
 // Send user to this link
   insertRecord(); //SQLite Code
  location.href = "game.html";
   // location.href = "http://www.takemehere.com"; });
```

So When i used the location.href like he putted it (= "http://www.takemehere.com";) The insertRecord() method is done with success (the object is added to the database)

But when I use the location.href = "game.html"; the game.html page is opened but the insertRecord() method is not done i tried to put the full path of game.html but the same problem persist Have you any idea please ? Thank u in advance

Comment: have you tried using set time out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `insertMethod()` calls some async functions to do database updating. So you should use a callback before doing anything else.

Something like this (i don't know what is inside of insertRecord method);

```
function insertRecord(callback) {
  // do all sorts of database job
  // when it's finished
  // fire your callback
  callback();
}

insertRecord(function() {
  location.href = "page.html";
});
```

EDIT: After your comment, i see you already have defined a function to run after sql which is `loadAndReset()`. So simply put `location.href = "page.html"` in that function, and it should work.

Comment: function insertRecord() {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
         tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [firstName.value], loadAndReset, onErrorInsert);
        });

Comment: function onErrorInsert(tx, error) {
        alert("Ce Login est utilisé choissez un autre");
        resetForm();   
   }